# Installing qmail on Linux CentOS 6 (switching from sendmail to qmail service)

Tags: linux, centos6, email

I'm following [Tom Clegg's guide](http://tomclegg.net/qmail-linux) on how to install qmail on Linux (the best I can anyhow) and in the section of his guide headlines 'Switching mail service from sendmail to qmail', I'm unfamiliar with specifically what I need to and wondered if someone could point me in the right direction.

The instruction is:-

```
Translate /home/*/.forward to /home/*/.qmail (details omitted).
```

Followed by:-

```
Translate /etc/mail/virtusertable to /var/qmail/alias/.qmail-* and /var/qmail/control/virtualdomains (details omitted).
```

I'm not familiar with what I should be typing in my terminal for this section (I'm not even sure what this command does either). The `Translate` command is not found if I try the above - what does the details omitted refer to as well, should I replacing this with something here?

Comment: Just curious: why are you choosing qmail over something reasonable like postfix or exim?

Comment: Because I haven't got a clue about the features and benefits between others plus as I was migrating from qmail on another server, figured it would be easiest. I've taken on board your suggestion though got postfix or exim which I'll look into. Thanks

Comment: qmail is (and has been) a dead, abandoned project for quite some time. For future support, bugfixes, security patches, etc, it's advisable to stay away from it.

Comment: Ah great, thanks for the advice (I've abandoned qmail) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "read the manual for qmail-local and re-create the same configuration in the format used by qmail-local".